# GUI Design Terminology

Tags: web, terminology, gui-design

I am looking for the graphic design terminology for describing themed buttons used in a web application. The way I understand it is that certain color/backgrounds are created and various sized and shaped buttons use the background to display.

I have seen them out there - but have no idea exactly how they are used or how to talk about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themeing applies to all controls across a page(s) typically, if you want to isolate a control then you would refer to themed control x. In your case a themed button.

Buttons are usually referred to as having text, image, image and text or bare image. In this scenario the theme could be applied to all these types of buttons excepting the bare image button. Using style (CSS) and or javascript.

Often time raw images are used for buttons in this case the image itself is encapsulateing the theme.
These are usually referred to as image buttons or picture buttons, you could say themed image button.